# Expected Value of Special Pairs of Cards

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

You have a standard 52-card deck of cards (13 values, 4 suites). Suppose all 52 cards are shuffled and layed on a table into a single row. A "special pair" of cards is the maximum number of non-overlapping consecutive pairs of cards where each pair has the same number written on both cards. For example, if the sequence "1 1 1" appeared in the row, it would count as one special pair of cards, and the sequence "1 1 1 1" would have a total of two special pairs of cards. What is the expected value of special pairs of cards of the row of the 52 cards?

I found the probability (not sure if I am correct) of one special pair of cards as 3/51 and the probability of two special pairs of cards as (3/51)(2/50)(1/49), but am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hint:  Use Linearity of Expectation.  some care needs to be taken because of the overlap condition, but it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I'm not sure how to address the cases where there's overlap either (i.e. 3 identical values in a row) with linearity of expectation.

Comment: Well,  introduce indicator variables $\{I_n\}_{n=1}^{51}$ which tell you if the $n^{th}$ slot is the first of a special pair.  $I_1$ is easy to analyze.  For $n>1$ the good patterns are $Y\bar XX$ or $XX\bar XX$ where $Y\neq X$ so just analyze those separately, and where the bar indicates the slot we are analyzing. (Note:  the $XXXX$ case is so rare that ignoring it should give a very good approximation).

Comment: As a (minor) variant:  get the expect number of doubles (where $XXX$ would count as $2$ doubles), subtract the expected number of triples (where $XXXX$ would count as $2$ triples) and add the expected number of quadruples.